# Android - open Telegram specific account from my own Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, telegram, start-activity

I am trying to open Telegram app with needed contact and I tried two diffrent ways and noone is not working.

First way:

I got userId, for example 1111111111 and if I open it from WEB it works fine: https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=u1111111111, but when I am trying to launch it from my app id doesn't work and always toast me `there is no Telegram account with this username`:

The code next:

```
Intent telegram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://t.me/1111111111")); //where 1111111111 - telegram userId
telegram.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
telegram.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
startActivity(telegram);
```

I asked Telegram support and they told me that url "https://t.me/ " can be used only with UserNames not UserId and did not give me any **url** that can be used for UserId. But UserNames cannot be got easily as well not every user has UserName.

Then I tried second way using URI scheme:

```
Intent telegram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
telegram.setData(Uri.parse("tg://msg?text=Hello&to=+496........."));
telegram.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
telegram.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
context.startActivity(telegram);
```

But it doesn't open needed contact only launch Telegram app. All contacts what I try are exist in my phone book. Why this URI scheme is not working?

"tg://msg?text=Hello&to=+496........."

If I use this scheme "tg://resolve?domain=BotSupport" it works fine and opens the chat with bot, but I need to open contact from my phone book.

Maybe somebody had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

We have two options here:

1. If the user have a **username** in Telegram, use the following URL replacing the **username** with original one.

   ```
   https://t.me/username
   ```
2. If you want to open the chat using **user_id**, use the following URL to open desired chat from your app replacing **xxxxxxxx** with the **user_id**.

   ```
   tg://openmessage?user_id=xxxxxxxx
   ```

For an example:

```
int userid = 1111111111
Intent tgintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                      Uri.parse("tg://openmessage?user_id=" + userid));
tgintent.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
startActivity(tgintent);
```

Comment: 1. does not apply to all contacts 2. does not work